# Listado de excepciones en JAVA

Tags: java

Quería saber como accedo desde Netbeans para ver los tipos de excepciones, sus caracteristicas y como funcionan.

Comment: te comento para lo que preguntas (si entiendo bien) es muy generico, pues las excepciones en Java son las misma (solo depende de la implementacion) en cualquier ide, creo que seria mejor que buscaras por google excepciones en Java si te gusta leer, y si no te gusta tanto pues lo mismo pero por YouTube, si te cierran la pregunta no te lo tomes a mal. Quizas te interese mirar este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por comentar! soy nuevo en esto, la próxima seré mas conciso gracias!

Comment: a qué te refieres con "características"?

Comment: como funcionan y en que caso se aplican.

Comment: sin ningun problema por mi parte. Por otro lado si despues de ver algun video sobre una excepcion en particular, tienes dudas como se usa por que se usa, por que no me funciona o lo que sea, pues puede crear una pregunta sobre tu duda y igual alguien te puede ayudar a entender sus caracteristicas ect Saludos

Comment: Te lo agradezco!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Las excepciones son objetos

- De la clase Exception, que hereda de `Throwable` y que contienen informacion del error que se ha producido
- En Java puede haber dos tipos de excepciones:

  Excepciones que no requieren comprobarse

  • Errores y excepciones de ejecución

  • Clase `RuntimeException`

  Excepciones que hay que comprobar

  • Heredan de la clase `Exception`

  • Todas las demás
- La excepcion puede ser capturada para tratarla `(catch)`

  catch (Excepción e) {tratamiento();}
- Cuando ocurre una excepcion se dice que se lanza `(throw)`

  throw new Excepcion();

Por otro lado quizas este grafico te ayude a tenerlas presentes de una manera mas visual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 5):

una excepción no es más que una clase, no es necesario utilizar netbeans ni ningun otro IDE para verlas, con abrir la documentación es suficiente. en resumen, cualquier clase que derive de java.lang.Exception es considerada una excepción, su significado varía de excepción a excepción.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

no es recomendable estudiar "todas" las excepciones de java, ya que por un lado son una gran cantidad, por otro lado algunas solo se aplican a contextos muy específicos.